# How can we query using javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, string, jsp

Hey! I want to check for a string value from a database without going to another jsp page. Since the server code is executed first I can't check it using javascript. Can anyone help please?

Comment: More description of your problem will be welcome, but I think ajax may be an option if you wish update the contents of the webpage from server with out refreshing the page.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot query a database directly from javascript. Nor should you be able or want to.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Oh, i'm sorry, i missed that "you can't use javascript". this answer is Javascript based, so might not work for you...

What you could do is to send a ajax request to a servercode page, which handles the request, query the database and check the string and then replies to the javascript whether the string is OK.

Look here:
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
or
http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/ajax.html

Good luck!